# remove consecutive identical rows by group

Tags: python, pandas

Remove rows

- with at least n (n = 3) consecutive identical values
- in all columns C1 and C2
- rows also must have the same the groups (ID), and
- they must be ordered by the Date.

Rows corresponding to missing dates are assumed to be identical to the one before them - so once they data is sorted by ID and Date, there is no need to check if the dates are consecutive.

I guess one way to do this is to forget about grouping and consider identical values of columns C1, C2, and ID.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"], 
                   'Date':  [pd.Timestamp('2019-07-12 01:00:00'),
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-07-13 01:00:00'),
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-07-14 01:00:00'),
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-07-15 01:00:00'),
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-07-16 01:00:00'),
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-07-17 01:00:00'), 
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-06-21 01:00:00'), 
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-07-12 01:00:00'),
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-07-13 01:00:00'),
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-07-14 01:00:00'),
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-07-16 01:00:00'),
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-07-17 01:00:00'),
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-07-18 01:00:00')],
                   'C1':[1.0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 3],
                   'C2':[3.0, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3]})
```

The desired outcome is

> ```
>    ID                Date   C1   C2
> 0   A 2019-07-12 01:00:00  1.0  3.0
> 4   A 2019-07-16 01:00:00  4.0  3.0
> 5   A 2019-07-17 01:00:00  3.0  3.0
> 6   B 2019-06-21 01:00:00  3.0  3.0
> 7   B 2019-07-12 01:00:00  3.0  3.0
> 8   B 2019-07-13 01:00:00  3.0  5.0
> 12  B 2019-07-18 01:00:00  3.0  3.0
> ```

Comment: Why isn't the last row included in the output?  The last row with the value of 3.

Comment: Thanks, that was a mistake. I'll add the last line.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this logic:

```
grp = (df.groupby(['ID'])['C2'].diff() != 0).cumsum()

mask = df.groupby(grp)['C2'].transform(lambda x: (x.count() < 3) | (x.notna().cumsum() > 3))

df[mask]
```

Output:

```
  ID                Date   C1   C2
0   A 2019-07-12 01:00:00  1.0  3.0
4   A 2019-07-16 01:00:00  4.0  3.0
5   A 2019-07-17 01:00:00  3.0  3.0
6   B 2019-06-21 01:00:00  3.0  3.0
7   B 2019-07-12 01:00:00  3.0  3.0
11  B 2019-07-17 01:00:00  5.0  5.0
12  B 2019-07-18 01:00:00  3.0  3.0
```

Details:

First, let's groupby ID and calculate the diff between consective rows, now where diff is not equal to 1, then use cumsum to define a group of consective same value.

Next, groupby the dataframe, df using the groups defined by step one. Using transform on any column without NaNs, you can the get the size of the group and using notna and cumsum to get a running count.

You should break this coded and look at the outputs of each step.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Do you mind explaining what you did?

Comment: @Suren Sure, give a minute, I will update the post with an details.

Comment: I initially thought this answers my question, but now i see this it only considers identical values in the column C2  (doesn't consider C1).

Comment: @Suren.. I am  bit confused. So if either C2 or C1 has three repeating values more that row?  So what if C1 has only two repeating values and C2 has three repeating values, do you want those rows removed?

Comment: If the consecutive rows r_1 to r_m, where m > n, have C1 = k1 and C2 = k2, then those rows should be removed.

Comment: "So what if C1 has only two repeating values and C2 has three repeating values, do you want those rows removed? " - No. C1 also have to have three repeating values for those rows to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You need first with agg

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"], 
                   'Date':  [pd.Timestamp('2019-07-12 01:00:00'),
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-07-13 01:00:00'),
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-07-14 01:00:00'),
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-07-15 01:00:00'),
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-07-16 01:00:00'),
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-07-17 01:00:00'), 
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-06-21 01:00:00'), 
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-07-12 01:00:00'),
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-07-13 01:00:00'),
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-07-14 01:00:00'),
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-07-16 01:00:00'),
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-07-17 01:00:00'),
                             pd.Timestamp('2019-07-18 01:00:00')],
                   'C1':[1.0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 3],
                   'C2':[3.0, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3]})

df2 = df.groupby(['ID', 'C1', 'C2']).agg({'Date' : 'first'}).reset_index()
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
  ID   C1   C2                Date
0  A  1.0  3.0 2019-07-12 01:00:00
1  A  3.0  3.0 2019-07-17 01:00:00
2  A  4.0  3.0 2019-07-16 01:00:00
3  A  4.0  4.0 2019-07-13 01:00:00
4  B  3.0  3.0 2019-06-21 01:00:00
5  B  3.0  5.0 2019-07-13 01:00:00
6  B  5.0  5.0 2019-07-14 01:00:00
```

Comment: Your answer looks quite nice. Do you mind explaining it a bit, please.

Comment: If the same values occur only twice consecutively, I don't want to remove those rows.  This removes those rows as well.

Comment: This only brings in the first, you can also add last to keep two rows but that - based on my try - only works when you have mandatory 2 or more repetition which is the not the case in your data